# como puedo ordenar 2 columnas por horario como si fuera una sola

Tags: php, mysql, ordenamiento

tengo 2 columnas, la primera es arrival_time, la segunda es pick_up, la cuestion es la siguiente, necesito ordenar los resultados dependiendo de que tipo de servicio sea, si es por ejemplo llegada (arrival) tiene que seleccionar el horario de la columna arrival_time, si es un servicio de salida o interhotel tiene que seleccionar su horario de la columna pick_up, y necesito ordenarlos por horario independientemente de que servicio séa, les dejo un ejemplo de lo que busco

llegada      10:00
salida       10:15
salida       11:00
llegada      11:20
interhotel   11:50

la cuestion es que si lo ordeno por ejemplo así `ORDER BY arrival_time ASC, pick_up ASC` si lo ordena, sin embargo lo ordena primero por arrival_time y despues por pick_up así:

llegada 10:00
llegada 11:20
salida 10:15
salida 11:00
interhotel 11:50

Como podría hacer para obtener el resultado que busco? he buscado por días en internet y no logro encontrar nada parecido, de antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo!

Aquí la consulta completa

```
SELECT name, pax, agency, origin, destination, internal_notes, 
departure_flight, departure_date, arrival_date, arrival_flight, 
TIME_FORMAT(arrival_time, '%H:%i') AS arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(pick_up, 
'%H:%i') AS pick_up, service_type FROM reservas WHERE arrival_date=? OR 
departure_date=? ORDER BY pick_up, arrival_time ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Como identificas que sea salida o llegada, coloca una condicional que te diga que es, y dependiendo si es salida selecciona `pick_up`, si es llegada selecciona `arrival_time`

```
SELECT ....., TIME_FORMAT(hora_programada, '%H:%i') FROM (
    SELECT ....., IF('verificar si salida', pick_up, arrival_time) AS hora_programada FROM .....
) AS t ORDER BY hora_programada
```

Comment: Perdon creo que me faltó agregar que recorro los resultados con un while, y dependiendo del tipo de servicio tomo pick up o arrival time, como lo haría de la consulta que me hiciste favor de proporcionarme? mi while va algo así (no es literal, es solo un ejemplo)

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($row['service_type']=arrival){
       echo $row['arrival_time'];
      }
      elseif($row['service_type']=departure){
       echo $row['pick_up'];
     else{
       echo $row['pick_up'];
        }
    }

como comento, es solo un ejemplo, te agradezco mucho el apoyo!

Comment: service_type que tipo de dato es, supongamos que es entero y el 1 representa la salida, en sql seria `IF(service_type = 1, pick_up, arrival_time) AS hora_programada`, si es cadena `IF(service_type = 'salida', pick_up, arrival_time) AS hora_programada`, en el if de la consulta verificarias, y obtendrias dicho dato, sobre la consulta padre lo ordenarias dependiendo de `hora_programada`, ya no necesitarias el `while` en tu código

Comment: Entiendo, sin embargo cada tipo de servicio tambien lleva campos llenados de forma diferente, es por eso que segun yo necesito el while, en ese caso podría tambien tomar los valores correctos de hora_programada? porque segun entiendo no podría elegir cual corresponde a que registro :S estoy perdido, no se como podría enseñarte mas de mi codigo para ver si me comprendes

Comment: en dado caso el while solo lo ocuparias para obtener los datos que correspondan a salida o llegada, ya estarian ordenados que es el problema que tenias en principío, o no?

Comment: Intenté implementar tu solución sin exito :( probablemente algo esté haciendo mal, de plano ya no encuentro como puedo hacer para ordenar los resultados :(